# Custom control size on InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I am trying to create a custom user control in WPF. I want to be able to set the size manually when I later use the control within another window.

As a short test I have just made a control comprising a canvas within a grid, which totally fills the control. When initialised it draws a rectangle within itself showing its size. I then position this on a window, making it whatever size I want.

However I now have problems, as if I make the height of the rectangle I draw

```
this.ActualHeight
```

then when the control initialises this value is still 0, and so I get nothing. If instead I use

```
this.Height
```

then I get the height that I made it during design time, and not the size I have subsequently made it within the window.

The height and width seem to be set within the XAML designer, so I don't know what to do.

Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're experiencing is how [WPF performs layout](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) and specifically how Canvas does not participate in Layout.

In your specific case you are setting the width of the Rectangle to Canvas.ActualWidth? Unless the width / height of the canvas have been explictly set then the ActualWidth/Actualheight will be zero, hence you can't get a point of reference within which to position children of Canvas. What I would do is bind the canvas width and height to its parent container (or set in code) to get the ActualWidth / ActualHeight correctly propagated.

As a point of interest try this example to understand how the WPF Layout engine works. The following code can force a height on a FrameworkElement to set the Width, Height as normal, then force a layout (measure, arrange pass) on the element in question. This causes the WPF layout engine to measure/arrange the element and propagate the Width, Height to ActualWidth, ActualHeight.

For example:

```
// Set the width, height you want
element.Width = 123;
element.Height = 456;

// Force measure/arrange
element.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); 
element.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, element.DesiredWidth, element.DesiredHeight));   

// Subject to sufficient space, the actual width, height will have 
// the values propagated from width/height after a measure and arrange call
double width = element.ActualWidth;
double height = element.ActualHeight;
```

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695101/why-are-actualwidth-and-actualheight-0-0-in-this-case) for clarity. I have used the above method occasionally to measure the text in a textblock so as to position correctly on a canvas.

Comment: Thanks again. I also found another way by accident, which was by initiating a redraw after a SizeChanged() event on my control, which I need to happen anyway for screen resizing.