# Get actual width of Grid that is set as Auto

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012),Is there any way to get `Grid` width which is set to `Auto`,
**Brief**: I have `StackPanel` with a `Grid` in it with `n` number of rows and `n` number of columns(Rows and Columns are generating dynamically).
I need to know `Grid` actual width which is in `StackPanel`, i tried

```
 1)var Actualwidth = grid.ActualWidth;            
 2)var Minwidth = grid.MinWidth;
 3)var width = grid.Width;
 4)var Renderwidth = grid.RenderSize.Width;
```

Where Results comes as follows

```
1 = 0.0
2 = 0.0
3 = NaN
4 = 0.0
```

Is there any way to get actual width, Please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be as well zero since it doesn't contain anything. Try stretching and getting width from parent container.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy Reznik, But I'm new to this, can you explain me or send me a link to how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

`ActualWidth` isn't set until after the control is measured and arranged.  Try handling the `OnLoaded` event and getting the width there.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695101/why-are-actualwidth-and-actualheight-0-0-in-this-case) for the explanation for wpf (same explanation for winrt).  For a windows 8 api see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth):

> For purposes of ElementName binding, ActualWidth does not post updates
>   when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated
>   nature). Do not attempt to use ActualWidth as a binding source for an
>   ElementName binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates
>   based on ActualWidth, use a SizeChanged handler.

Comment: If this answers your question then please mark it as the answer.