# Why would actual width be zero when width is set to a value. WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, actualwidth, actualheight

I have a class that extends a `Canvas`.  On creation I explicitly set its width to a value:

```
Public Sub New(w As Integer, h As Integer)
    Me.Width = w
    Me.Height = h
End Sub
```

Now I add instances of this to a canvas to another canvas using `cnvPreview.Children.Add(e)` where `e` is the instance of my extended canvas.

However when I run the application, the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of these canvases are 0.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: When are you reading the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHight`?

Comment: Just after I added the children to the canvas, I used a messagebox to debug.

Comment: Don't canvas's shrink to the smallest size possible, yet still display fully their own children? Might this be causing the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` values to be zero. Try adding say, a `TextBlock` and reading the values then.

Comment: @Asryael This seems to be the case, when only the background colour is changed, I can see the canvas occupies the area I specified but the `actualHeight` and `actualWidth` is still zero.  If a component is added the desired size is shown. Thanx.

Comment: @Blaffie Added comment as answer. Please mark as answer if it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `Canvas's` shrink to the smallest size possible, yet still display fully their own children? Might this be causing the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` values to be zero. Try adding say, a `TextBlock` and reading the values then.

I believe that this is explained better on this other post: [Why are ActualWidth and ActualHeight 0.0 in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695101/why-are-actualwidth-and-actualheight-0-0-in-this-case)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` will give you the values after rendering the control. Suppose if the `Canvas` `Height` and `Width` is **50** and after rendering the `Canvas` is shrinked then it will return a lower `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` value or maybe zero if not visible.