# Object's ActualWidth and ActualHeight reporting as 0?

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement, actualwidth, actualheight

I have an application that contains several instances of a `Grid` that inherits from an Abstract class extending `UserControl` like this:

```
<abstract:ScoringGrid x:Class="ReadProject.Repeater.ScoringGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:abstract="clr-namespace:ReadProject.AbstractRepeater"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="ScoringGridInstance" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
....
```

and the class they inherit from (which is a very basic class with just a few methods and properties):

```
public abstract partial class ScoringGrid : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{...
```

These grids are built dynamically at runtime and each one can vary in size. When the user closes the application, I want to capture a screenshot of each `Grid` and save them to the local machine.  To do this, I created a method to get the objects size and save it to a file using `RenderTargetBitmap()`.  A lot of them save without issue, however some of the grids are returning an `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of `0` and thus not saving.  I'm uncertain of where to start debugging this issue since they are all instances of the same exact object; how could it be possible that some of them have their `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` set and others do not?  They all display without issue in the application.

Let me know if you need more information/code.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you try to read these values after user control is loaded?

Comment: also check the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695101/why-are-actualwidth-and-actualheight-0-0-in-this-case

Comment: @iltzortz I looked at the question you linked and tried looping through each `Grid` and called `Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));` on each one before attempting to get the size; it results in the same issue.

Comment: i was talking about the part of the answer that says: `You can force these to be computed earlier by simply calling the window's Measure() and Arrange() methods manually after the window's InitializeComponent() returns.`

No arguments to the measure and arrange functions

Comment: I saw this in a comment for that answer which is why I passed in the parameters to `Measure()`: `window.Measure returns void.`  I did, however, add a call to `Arrange()` for each one and that seemed to work.  What exactly are those doing, though, and why are they necessary?  Also I have bigger `Grids` that encapsulate two of the `ScoringGrid`s, but when I try to do the same thing with those, only the top portion is captured and not the whole thing, any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I was able resolve the issue by adding these calls to each `UserControl` before capturing a screenshot of them:

```
scoreGrid.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                scoreGrid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, scoreGrid.ScoreGridInstance.DesiredSize.Width, scoreGrid.ScoreGridInstance.DesiredSize.Height));
```