# Obtaining Canvas dimensions wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, actualwidth, actualheight

I have the following code:

**Xaml**

```
<GroupBox x:Name="FrameStatusGroupBox" Header="Frame Status" Foreground="DarkRed" Grid.Row="3">
     <ItemsControl x:Name="FrameStatusItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding KeepFramesSection.FrameStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <Canvas x:Name="FrameStatusCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="{Binding MarkingFileLoaded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
             </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     </ItemsControl>
</GroupBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
foreach (var currentCanvas in ListOfCanvases)
{
     var widthRatio = FrameStatus.ActualWidth / currentCanvas.ActualWidth;
     var heightRatio = FrameStatus.ActualHeight / currentCanvas.ActualHeight;

     foreach (var currentBoundingBox in currentCanvas.Children)
     {
           var savedObj = XamlWriter.Save(currentBoundingBox);
           var reader = new StringReader(savedObj);
           var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
           var newChild = (UIElement) XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

           var p = ((UIElement) currentBoundingBox).TransformToAncestor(currentCanvas)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

           p.X *= widthRatio;
           p.Y *= heightRatio;

           Canvas.SetLeft(newChild, p.X);
           Canvas.SetTop(newChild, p.Y);

           FrameStatus.Children.Add(newChild);
     }
}

FrameStatus.UpdateLayout();
```

I'm trying to get the dimensions of both the original `Canvas` and the new `Canvas` because I want to copy the children from one to the other, and their sizes are different.

When doing that, for some reason, this code: `FrameStatus.ActualWidth` and this code: `FrameStatus.ActualHeight` return both 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you wait until your view is fully loaded? If you try to access these properties to early they might not be initialized yet.

Another answer ([Why are ActualWidth and ActualHeight 0.0 in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695101/why-are-actualwidth-and-actualheight-0-0-in-this-case)) suggests to call

```
window.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
window.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, window.DesiredWidth, window.DesiredHeight));
```

measure and arrange which forces a recalculation of the dimensions of your objects in your view.