# ActualWidth always returns 0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, actualwidth

The `ActualWidth` of `StretchingGrid` is always 0.
I tried **a lot** of solutions i found here (`UpdateLayout()`,....), but none of them worked for me.

```
<Grid x:Name="StretchingGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red">
         <Grid x:Name="GridMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="LightBlue" Width="30">

         </Grid>
    </Grid>


    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
         <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="30"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=StretchingGrid}"/>
         </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the `UpdateLayout`? If you are calling it in the consctructor, the `FrameworkElement` is probably not render yet, so the `ActualWidth` will be 0

Comment: Right after `InitializeComponent()`. I also tried it in the Eventhandler that fires the Storyboard.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the problem and cannot try it now, but I would do the `UpdateLayout` it on the `Load` of the Window and check if I get the value of `ActualWidth` from code behind first.

Comment: Did not work  :/

Comment: You mean it is still 0 when you are accesing it after Load()?

Comment: Did you put something in GridMenu?

Comment: `ActualWidth` is null even when i call it in de `Window_Loaded` Eventhandler.

Comment: In `GridMenu` there are some Textboxes and Comboboxes.

Comment: @DavidAichinger: It would be helpful if you could provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem is just in this piece of code...i think it doesn't matter how many elements are in the grid...in Codebehind there ist just a Button_Click Handler that fires the Storyboard

Comment: Try this approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695518/2315752

Comment: @Nekeniehl i tried this already, but it didn't work :/. I called the `Measure()` and `Arrange()` right after `InitializeComponent()`, is that correct?

Comment: @DavidAichinger, Could you please post the .cs file of this view?