# At what point is a UIElement loaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, loaded

I have the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas Name="Canvas_Main" />
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle lastRectangle = null;
        Random random = new Random(0);
        for (Int32 counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            rectangle.Width = random.Next(100, 200);
            rectangle.Height = counter * 100;
            Canvas_Main.Children.Add(rectangle);
            if (lastRectangle == null) {
                Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, 0);
                Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, lastRectangle.ActualWidth);
                Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, 0);
            }
            lastRectangle = rectangle;
        }
    }

}
```

This isn't working as expected (laying each rectangle diagonally next to each other), as `lastRectangle.ActualWidth` is 0. As I understand things from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695518/14385915), it is because lastRectangle has not been measured and arranged.

I am curious, at what point would the measuring and arranging be done, if not when added to a container that is already visible and loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Framework.Loaded` event of an element is raised after the measure and arrange layout pass, but before the rendering of the element.

The complete layout pass is initialized when `UIElement.InvalidateMeasure` for an asynchronous layout pass or `UIElement.UpdateLayout` for a synchronous layout pass was invoked on the element.

In your scenario the `Window.Loaded`event handler is invoked, which means that the `Window` and the `Canvas` are both loaded (but not rendered).
Now you start to add new `UIElement` elements to the `Canvas`.

`Canvas.Children.Add` should invoke the `InvalidateMeasure` method. Because `InvalidateMeasure` triggers an asynchronous layout pass, the `Canvas` and therefore the current child element will be enqueued into the layout queue and the context continues execution (adding more rectangles).
Because there is already a pending layout pass due to the freshly added element, you should avoid calling `UIElement.Measure` manually (this are recursive calls and quite expensive when considering performance).

Once the context has completed, the elements in the queue, that are waiting for their layout pass and final rendering, will be handled and `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` are invoked recursively on those elements (`Canvas` and its children).
As a result, `UIElement.RenderSize` can be calculated by the layout system.
At this moment, the new `FrameworkElement.ActualWidth` will be available.

This is the moment the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event of the added elements (the rectangles) is finally raised.

To solve your problem you have to either use `Rectangle.Width` instead
or wait for each `Rectangle.Laoded` event before adding the next:

```
private int ShapeCount { get; set; }
private const int MaxShapes = 5;
private Point ShapeBPosition { get; set; }

private void MainWindow_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.ShapePosition = new Point();
  AddRectangle(this.ShapePosition);
}

private void AddRectangle(Point position)
{
  Random random = new Random();
  Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
  rectangle.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

  rectangle.Width = random.Next(100, 200);
  rectangle.Height = ++this.ShapeCount * 100;

  Canvas_Main.Children.Add(rectangle);
  Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, position.X);
  Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, position.Y);

  rectangle.Loaded += OnRectangleLoaded;
}

private void OnRectangleLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var rectangle = sender as Rectangle;

  rectangle.Loaded -= OnRectangleLoaded;
  if (this.ShapeCount == MainWindow.MaxShapes)
  {
    return;
  }

  // this.ShapePosition is struct => modify copy
  Point position = this.ShapePosition; 
  position.Offset(rectangle.ActualWidth, 0);
  this.ShapePosition = position;
  AddRectangle(this.ShapePosition);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - you've given me plenty of methods and events to look up for further details.

Answer (score -2):

The measuring and arranging has been completed for the window. But you are now creating new child controls, which will ordinarily not be measured/arranged until the window's next layout pass.

You can force this to happen immediately by calling the `Measure` method of each rectangle at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thank you. However, then what causes the layout method of a window to be called? I cannot imagine this running in a timer, yet adding or removing a child does not trigger the layout? Would appreciate if it you could expand your answer.

Comment: At the top of every UI application is a `while` loop which runs over and over until the application exits. The layout pass is one of the stages that WPF's loop executes. (To pre-empt your probable next question, avoid choking up a CPU core the loop will sit idle at some point until the OS prompts it to continue, e.g. by notifying it about user input.)