# WPF - How to conditionally set SizeToContent?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

[image]

I have a resizable custom control window where the image stretches until it hits either the available height or the available width, as pictured above. This is my attempt at setting the window's initial size:

```
Width = 700;
Height = Math.Min(DesiredSize.Height, System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.75);
```

**How do I set the starting height of the window to be the 'SizeToContent' height, or 75% of the screen height, whichever is less?**

If I set `SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height`, the image will stretch to the available width while treating the height as infinite, and this will determine the window height. So if the image is much more wide than tall, I will get the layout on the right above but without extra space above and below the picture (which is good). If the image is much more tall than wide, I will get a window much taller than the screen. Setting the MaxHeight to the screen height works okay, but I'd rather have the initial max to be 75% of the screen height while allowing resizing above 75%.

Both the `DesiredSize.Height` and the `ActualHeight` always seem to be zero. I've tried what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695518), and I've also tried temporarily setting `SizeToContent` and using the `ActualHeight`; here's one attempt combining both (at the end of the `FooView()` constructor pasted below):

```
MaxWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
MaxHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
Width = 700;
SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height;
UpdateLayout();
Measure(new Size(Width, double.PositiveInfinity));
Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, DesiredSize.Width, DesiredSize.Height));
UpdateLayout();
Height = ActualHeight;
SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
```

Here's another attempt. It sets the height to less than fits even the text and buttons, but if I remove both `SizeToContent` lines it does at least work to set a maximum initial size of 75% screen height and a max resizing height of 100%.

```
MaxWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
MaxHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.75;
Width = 700;
SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height;
Loaded += delegate
{
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
    MaxHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
};
```

FooView.xaml.cs and FooView.xaml:

```
namespace Foo.View
{
    public partial class FooView : MetroWindow
    {
        private readonly FooViewModel _viewModel;

        public FooView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // command line args

            _viewModel = new FooViewModel(commandLineArguments, Width, Height);
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            _viewModel.Initialize();

            // style, color

            MaxWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            MaxHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            Width = 700;
            Height = Math.Min(DesiredSize.Height, System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.75);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<mah:MetroWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        Top="100"
        Left="100"
        ResizeMode="CanResize"

        <!-- etc -->
        >

    <!-- styles, brushes... -->

    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrushDark}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="23" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Border BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="ContentBorder" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{Binding BottomRowBrush}">
            <!-- opacity mask -->

            <Grid Background="{StaticResource Background}">
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="{StaticResource Container2}">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryText}" Background="{StaticResource Container2}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button Visibility="{Binding YesVisibility}" x:Name="YES" Margin="0,0,20,0" Height="40" Width="150" FontSize="22" FontWeight="DemiBold" Content="YES" Foreground="{StaticResource CTAPrimary2}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Visibility="{Binding NoVisibility}" x:Name="NO" Margin="0,0,20,0" Height="40" Width="150" FontSize="22" FontWeight="DemiBold" Content="NO" Foreground="{StaticResource CTAPrimary2}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Visibility="{Binding ContinueVisibility}" x:Name="CONTINUE" Margin="0,0,20,0" Height="40" Width="150" FontSize="22" FontWeight="DemiBold" Content="CONTINUE" Foreground="{StaticResource CTAPrimary2}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Visibility="{Binding ExitVisibility}" x:Name="EXIT" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="150" FontSize="22" FontWeight="DemiBold" Content="EXIT" Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryText}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

    <!-- bottom row -->

    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: `_viewModel.Initialize();` should be called from the Loaded event handler. Initialize could then be even asynchronous if required. You simply have to implement the rules that you have postulated: `"IF the image_width > image_height THEN SizeToContent.Height" OR "IF the image_height > image_width THEN 75%_of_screen_height"`

Comment: I didn't mean those as precise rules, rather just a general description of the two pictured scenarios. Edited to clarify "much more wide than tall" and vice versa. Btw, I never noticed that Width and Height are given as arguments to FooViewModel... maybe that's something to do with it. (I didn't write this code from scratch.)

Comment: I find your description difficult to understand. Your sizing clearly is subject of rules (or constraints). You should be able to postulate those constraints. From what I have understood you should set the `SizeToContent` to `SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight`. Then e.g. inside the `MeasureOverride` method or, in case this is supposed to be a one-time initialization job, inside the Loaded event handler, check the total height of the `Window` and limit it to the actual screen height. If the image itself is configured to fill the available space this should yield you your desired results.

Comment: If this is not what you want, you should provide the correct constraints or elaborate more on the details.

Comment: @BionicCode Width should just be 700, not sized to content. Height should be sized to content, but max 75% of screen height. The problem is I don't know how to check the actual height of the window. Again, `ActualHeight` doesn't work.

Comment: There should be size values. If I understood you correctly you are configuring the size from the constructor? Then this is an issue as in the constructor the instance is nor constructed yet (hence the word constructor). Not talking about rendering at this point. To get the final rendered size you should set the initial values in the constructor (Width and SizeToContent) and then adjust the height in the Loaded event handler. The Loaded event is the moment when the control is fully rendered initially.

Comment: This code does not belong into the view model, by the way. Not sure why the view model is involved into the layout management.

Comment: @BionicCode `ActualHeight` doesn't work in Loaded either. If I set `SizeToContent.Height` in the constructor and `SizeToContent.Manual` in Loaded, I get a different result - height too short even for text+buttons - than if I set only `SizeToContent.Height` or set neither. This short height is apparently what `ActualHeight`  is set to as doing the following in Loaded does not help: `double d = ActualHeight; SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual; Height = d;`

Comment: @BionicCode Where should the code be? I have `App.xaml`, `App.xaml.cs`, `View\FooView.xaml`, `View\FooView.xaml.cs`, `View\FooResources.xaml`, `View_Model\FooViewModel.cs`, `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`, `Properties\Resources.Designer.cs`, `Properties\Resources.resx`, `Properties\Settings.Designer.cs`, `Properties\Settings.settings`.